# Trying to duplicate a trumpet cleaning solution that isn’t available on the market

Tags: organic-chemistry

There is a product called “Herco Spitballs” which are small foam cylinders soaked in solution which are used to clean brass wind instruments like trumpets.  The “Spitball” is inserted into one end of the horn and then blown through the entire instrument.  The solution runs out long before the spitballs do, but the solution is not available.  I’ve written to the manufacturer and haven’t gotten a response.  The solution is .5% Amine Polyglycol Condensate, .5% Isopropyl Alcohol, and 99% inert ingredients (probably water).  I need to know what Amine Polyglycol Condensate is and where to get it.  I don’t need much.  8 ounces would last for years.  Can you help me to find some?

Comment: I think it is this stuff  https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/07964?lang=en&region=GB

Comment: I´m sure you can just use distilled water.

Comment: Why not using a swap in sections accessible by remove of mouth piece and slides, prior / after the valves, as wood winds and e.g., French horns (around 3:09 min of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zslhbh5Exgg)?  While the disassembled b-trumpet on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trumpet shows not all corners are accessible by this, probably musicSE may be a better audience re alternatives for now since music dealers / conservatoiries (colleagues / teachers) probably are closed in your region as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think the question is more suitable for music.SE.

Comment: Brass cleaning compositions from home ingredients provided here https://www.thoughtco.com/make-copper-and-brass-cleaner-602200 .

Comment: Waylander is on the right track.  I’m just wondering whether it really is the same stuff.  Karl is right.  I can use distilled water, but that isn’t the question.  The question is, what is Amine Polyglycol Condensate, and where can it be obtained in small quantities?  Buttonwood is correct in thinking that the most thorough way to clean a trumpet is to take it apart, but one doesn’t do that every day.  Buttonwood’s vote to disallow the question is strange, because the question is where to get the chemical.  Ajkoer’s response is tangential—this is a search for a specific chemical.